# Can long-run variance of an ARMA process be lower than its error variance?

Tags: time-series, variance, arima

Consider an ARMA process expressed in lag operator notation,
$$
\Phi(L)x_t=\theta(L)\varepsilon_t.
$$ Let $\text{Var}(\varepsilon_t)=\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}$.

**Question:** Can the long-run variance of $x_t$ be lower than the error variance? If so, could you provide an example?

<sub>A related thread with an answer that may help answer my question is ["Long-run variance of ARMA(p,q)"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409277).</sub>
<sub>A related **new question** is ["Can unconditional variance of an ARMA process be lower than its error variance?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507648).</sub>

Comment: The second link is the same as the first one

Comment: @gunes, good catch! Now fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote the long-run variance as $\operatorname{var}_L(y_t)$ to prevent confusion. From the formula provided in the linked post, a proper choice of coefficients can lead to smaller long-run variance. Let our process be defined as
$$y_t=e_t-0.6e_{t-1}$$ then, the long-run variance will be $$\operatorname{var}_L(y_t)=\sigma^2 \left(\frac{1-0.6}{1}\right)^2=0.16\sigma^2<\sigma^2$$
Note that the missing definiton of coefficients in that post is ($b_0=1$)
$$y_t=\sum_{i=1}^p a_py_{t-p}+\sum_{i=0}^q b_qe_{t-q}$$

Comment: I believe the formula there is wrong. Your example yields $\text{Var}(x_t)=1.36\sigma^2_\varepsilon>\sigma^2_\varepsilon$. Here is a quick simulation to show that: `n=1e6; set.seed(1); e=rnorm(n); x=arima.sim(model=list(ma1=-0.6),n=n,innov=e); var(e); var(x)`.

Comment: @RichardHardy But, long-term variance is not $var(x_t)=\gamma(0)$, where $\gamma(t)$ is the auto covariance function. We also have $\gamma(1)=\gamma(-1)=-0.6\sigma^2$ and higher order covariances $0$, which yields $$\operatorname{var}_L(y_t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \gamma(k) = 0.16\sigma^2$$

Comment: Ahh, I forgot what the term *long-run variance* actually means. I meant to ask about the unconditional variance of $x$ instead, which I actually did by writing $\text{Var}(x_t)$. I will edit the question to clarify. Or better yet, I will post a new question so that your answer gets the credit it deserves. ... And I did: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507648) is my new question.