# Can unconditional variance of an ARMA process be lower than its error variance?

Tags: time-series, variance, arima

Consider an ARMA process expressed in lag operator notation,
$$
\Phi(L)x_t=\theta(L)\varepsilon_t.
$$ Let $\text{Var}(\varepsilon_t)=\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}$.

**Question:** Can the unconditional variance of $x_t$ be lower than the error variance, $\text{Var}(x_t)<\text{Var}(\varepsilon_t)$? If so, could you provide an example?

<sub>A related older question is ["Can long-run variance of an ARMA process be lower than its error variance?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507584).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

- $\theta_0 = 1$ in polynomial $\theta(L)$,
- $\phi_0 = 1$ in polynomial $\Phi(L)$,
- there are no negative powers in $\Phi(L)$ and $\theta(L)$ (no looking ahead),

we can write:
$$
x_t = E[x_t | F_{t-1}] + \varepsilon_t.
$$

Then our insights are a consequence of
$$
Var[x_t] = E[Var[x_t | F_{t-1}]] + Var[E[x_t | F_{t-1}]] \geq E[Var[x_t | F_{t-1}]] =
Var[\varepsilon_t].
$$
Please correct me if I misunderstood your set-up.

Comment: I think you understood it exactly right.